Understanding the Constant in Section 2.2 of "An Extension Problem Related to the Fractional Laplacian" by Caffarelli and Silvestre
In the paper "An Extension Problem Related to the Fractional Laplacian" by Caffarelli and Silvestre (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608640), in Section 2.2 (Fundamental solution at the origin), the constant $C_k$ is given by the formula:
$$ C_k = \frac{\pi^{k/2} \Gamma( k/2 -1)}{4}. $$
To provide some context, the fundamental solution $\Gamma(X)$ for the equation at the origin in $n+1+a$ dimensions is given by:
$$ \Gamma(X) = C_{n+1+a} \frac{1}{|X|^{n-1+a}}, $$
where $X = (x, y)$ and $|X|$ denotes the Euclidean norm.
I would like to understand why the constant $C_k$ takes this particular form. Could someone provide a detailed explanation or derivation of this formula?
For reference, the variables in this context are defined as follows:

$X$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1+a}$.
$|X|$ is the Euclidean distance of $X$ from the origin.
$\Gamma( k/2 -1)$ is the Gamma function evaluated at $k/2 - 1$. (Probably some abuse of notation, I am not so sure)

